# glassfish confusing database name with username

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, glassfish, connection-pooling

Im having very strange issue with glassfish 4. If I specify **wrong** username/password for my JDBC connection pool and try to ping, I get (as expected):

```
An error has occurred
Ping Connection Pool failed for scrumkinPool. Connection could not be allocated because: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "notAnActualUser" Please check the server.log for more details.
```

If I type in **real** username/password, I get (as **NOT** expected):

```
An error has occurred Ping Connection Pool failed for scrumkinPool.
Connection could not be allocated because: FATAL: database "anActualUser" does not exist Please check the server.log for more details.
```

As it can be seen, glassfish is interpreting "username" field as "databaseName" field.
But if I specify "postgres" as username (built in super user role), it pings successfully.

Note that inbetween it actually worked as it should, but then again started not to.

Im using PostgreSQL 9.3 database.

Answer (score 2):

> As it can be seen, glassfish is interpreting "username" field as "databaseName" field.

Actually, that's normal behaviour for PostgreSQL's `libpq` and `PgJDBC`. *If you do not specify a database name*, PostgreSQL defaults to a database named after the user you're connecting as.

I'd say you aren't actually specifying the database you want to connect to, so it's falling back to this default. It's hard to be sure because you didn't show your configuration.

Comment: no actually it was URL parameter that was the culprit... see my answer.

Comment: @user2340939 That makes sense, as the JDBC URL specifies the database to connect to.

Answer (score 2):

The workaround from Kiril ist working! Thx!

update the Attribute url to

> jdbc:postgresql://localhost/**databaseName**?

There is a Bug...

I'm Using - Adminconsole Glasfish and had the same phenomenon -

> [JDBC42 Postgresql Driver, Version 9.4-1207](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-9.4.1207.jar)
>
> GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1 (build 13)
>
> Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Greetings Sail

Answer (score 1):

In GlassFish 4 and postgresql9.3 I fixed this problem by adding databaseName to Url.
Like this:

*jdbc:postgresql://localhost/**databaseName**?loginTimeout=...*

Also works if I clear URL field

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Glassfish 4 and PostgreSQL 9.3. Sometimes it could be resolved temporarily by deleting the connection pool and adding it again. The only way I found to resolve it permanently was to downgrade the JDBC driver.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

I couldn't see the answer explicitly above, but realised that despite providing a "databaseName" property field, glassfish did not update this into the URL. So I am specifying a databaseName but as it's not in the URL by default, postgres isn't receiving it and defaults to the username.

The solution was to specify the databaseName both in the databaseName property AND add it to the URL after the hostname.